# PyCharm unittest error: Provide a qualified name of function, class or a module

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm

How to get rid of this annoying error? I do not understand what it want me to do.
[This happens when I am trying to run a test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx8hF.png)
Clicking on "Run" follows up with the following
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21bhV.png)
Clicking on "Continue Anyway" runs the tests normally.
So what should I do in order to stop this window from popping up every time I ran the tests?

Updated:
Here is what I've found myself meanwhile:
From [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/testing/PyTestsShared.kt)

```
if (targetType == PyRunTargetVariant.PYTHON && !isWellFormed()) {
      throw RuntimeConfigurationError("Provide a qualified name of function, class or a module")
    }
```

And a function isWellFormed() declaration from [here](http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=blob;f=python/src/com/jetbrains/extensions/TargetWithVariantExt.kt;h=0caea52ceff043a34fb2e4b325dec7b3c5bde236;hb=6e89c1f9c6a64d4ddf4484c144bbe250836c690b)

```
/**
  * Sanity check for "target" value. Does not resolve target, only check its syntax
  * CUSTOM type is not checked.
  */
 fun TargetWithVariant.isWellFormed() = when (targetVariant) {
   PyRunTargetVariant.PYTHON -> Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$").matches(target ?: "")
   PyRunTargetVariant.PATH -> !VfsUtil.isBadName(target)
   else -> true
 }
```

Everything looks good with a regex of my test class and method names.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ok, this is really weird.
I took a good look at a regex and found that it doesn't want any '-' in the target path. So renaming a filename from ads_wrapper-tests.py to ads_wrapper_tests.py solves the problem and the window is not popping up any more.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still experiencing this issue 2 years later.

Comment: Just came across this now. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This is the trick, thanks. Hyphens in the file name are really problematic, in addition to this issue, PyCharm even fails to import if your file has hyphens rather than underscores.

Comment: Year 2023 and it gives same error if the filename starts with a digit. I have to check the rules around filenames in python.

Answer (score 0):

With this issue [Error: Provide a qualified name of a function, class or module](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48747) just got fixed, soon Pycharm would allow using all valid identifier names in target name.